# How to receive model object sent by ajax call in a controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I sent an object to controllers action thorugh ajax , but I don't know how to recevie the object in controller. My ajax call is :

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create","Home")',
            data: { ID: '@Model.ID', Name: '@Model.Name'}
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Added :" + msg);
        });
```

This should work , BUt I can't figure out how to recevie the object in controller. I wrote this :

```
    public ActionResult Create(Home h)
    {

    }
```

But it is not working . I neeed help in this , Thanks in advance.

My Home class :

```
public class Home
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your `Home` class pls

Comment: I haven added Home class

Comment: What type of data you want to receive? Your `Create` action should to return `ActionResult` type, not `string`

Comment: I just want to receive the object or ID and Name , which I sent from the AJAX call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action should be like thus:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Home h)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // put you code here
}
```

Comment: After writing this action , I wrote this h.ID; to access the ID data , but it is not displaying anything